# Tensorflow ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental_functions_run_eagerly' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I keep on getting the following error while making imports:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental_functions_run_eagerly' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function'
```

I have alread tried using `pip` to uninstall and reinstall tensorflow.

The errors occur while I'm trying to import tensorflow but here are all of them:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from tf import keras
```

I'm running `Python 3.7.9` on Windows 10. I can't import Tensorflow due to the error, but according to `pip list` these are my install versions:

```
jupyter_client               7.4.7
jupyter_core                 4.11.2
jupyter-server               1.23.2
jupyterlab                   3.5.0
jupyterlab-pygments          0.2.2
jupyterlab_server            2.16.3
jupyterthemes                0.20.0
keras                        2.11.0
tensorboard                  2.11.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.11.0
tensorflow-cpu               2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.11.0
tensorflow-intel             2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.27.0
termcolor                    2.1.0
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you share all the imports you are trying to do?
Also if you simply try to `import tensorflow as tf` will it still give you an error?

Comment: It does not show any error, when I tried replicating the above code in the same given environment(Windows 10, jupyter notebook, python 3.7 and TF 2.11). You can try again by installing the python version 3.8. Also, please import keras by providing the complete inherited base API name as `from tensorflow import keras`.

Comment: Having the same error, if someone has a solution that will be great.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out why this is happening.
The reason is Tensorflow **2.10** is the last release which supports GPU on native Windows.

You can learn more about this from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native).

You can try installing a Tensorflow version earlier than **2.11**.

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure the tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu are upgrades by using these codes.

```py
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
pip install tensorflow-gpu --upgrade
```

then make sure the keras version is 2.3.1 + and upgrade it if it is not.

```py
pip install keras --upgrade
```

these steps worked for me.

Good Luck

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can resolve it.
Do you have another method to solve it?

It started after I have tried to install `tesorflow-gpu==2.10.1`. I believe that it uninstalled one important pip\package

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me while installing cuda to use tensorflow on GPU and took me hours to fix. I first installed Tensorflow 2.11, which was - I guess - responsible for all my troubles. To fix it, I used :

```
    pip list 
    pip uninstall tensor... # all your tensorflow modules : replace ... by each names
```

for every modules related to keras and tensorflow. Once everything was cleared, I reinstalled Tensorflow 2.9, for compatibility issues.

```
    pip install tensorflow==2.9
```

By the way, if it is of any use to anyone, my final configuration that works to use tensorflow on my GPU (Windows 10-NVIDIA T600) was the following (after numerous fails!) :

- Visual Studio 2019 Community
- CUDA v11.2
- cuDNN v8.1
- Tensorflow 2.9
- Python 3.9.16

And I've followed the steps detailed in https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/IubEtS2JAiY

Good luck !